# Dependency Size Database and Alter table

Tags: sql, sql-server

is the connection between the size of a database and the speed in which a command as below is 
completed dependending on the data in the column? Does "It" have to check whether it is possible to change the datatype depending on the entries? For the 12,5 mln records it takes about 
15 minutes.

Code:

```
USE RDW_DB
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.RDWTabel
    ALTER COLUMN Aantalcilinders SmallInt
```

Answer (score 7):

All ALTER COLUMN operations are implemented as an add of a new column and drop of the old column:

- add a new column of the new type
- run an internal `UPDATE <table> SET <newcolumn> = CAST(<oldcolumn> as <newtype>);`
- mark the old column as dropped

You can inspect a table structure after an ALTER COLUMN and see all the dropped, hidden columns. See [SQL Server table columns under the hood](http://rusanu.com/2011/10/20/sql-server-table-columns-under-the-hood/).

As you can see, this results in a size-of-data update that must touch every row to populate the values of the new column. This takes time on its own on a big table, but the usual problem is from the log growth. As the operation must be accomplished in a single transaction, the log must grow to accommodate this change. Often newbs run out of disk space when doing such changes.

Certain operations *may* be accomplished 'inline'. IF the new type fits in the space reserved for the old type and the on-disk layout is compatible then the update is not required: the new column is literally overlayed on top of the old column data. The article linked above exemplifies this. Also operations on *variable length* types that change the length are often not required to change the data on-disk and are much faster.

Additionally any ALTER operation requires an exclusive schema modification lock on the table. This will block, waiting for any current activity (queries) to drain out. Often time the perceived duration time is due to locking wait, not execution. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) for more details.

Finally some ALTER COLUMN operations do not need to modify the existing data but they do need to validate the existing data, to ensure it matches the requirements of the new type. Instead of running an UPDATE they will run a SELECT (they will scan the data) which will still be size-of-data, but at least won't generate any log.

In your case `ALTER COLUMN Aantalcilinders SmallInt` is impossible to tell whether the operation was size-of-data or not. It depends on what was the previous type of `Aantalcilinders`. If the new type grew the size then it requires a size-of-data update. Eg. if the previous type was `tinyint` then the ALTER COLUMN will have to update every row.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the type of a column, the data generally needs to be rewritten.  For instance, if the data were originally an integer, then each record will be two bytes shorter after this operation.  This affects the layout of records on a page as well as the allocation of pages.  Every page needs to be touched.

I believe there are some operations in SQL Server that you can do on a column that do no affect the layout.  One of them is changing a column from nullable to not-nullable, because the null flags are stored for every column, regardless of nullability.